# Rutherford experiment and particles

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation

The Rutherford experiment proved that the Thomson model was incorrect and the Rutherford model was the right one, this because the $\alpha$ particles were deflected by the nucleus and in the Thomson model this was not possible. The question is: since in the Thomson model we have the electrons, which have negative charge, why an $\alpha$ particle shouldn't be deflected? I know that the total charge in Thomson model is $0$ so there is no Coulomb interaction, but $\alpha$ particles maybe could touch the electrons and like a classical collision change their trajectory. Is it possible that $\alpha$ particles and electrons touch each other and change their trajectories not only beacuse of Coulomb interaction but also beacuse they "touch", like a neutron against another neutron? All this not considering MQ which did not exist at the time of Rutherford experiment, so particles were just particles and not waves.

Comment: Electrons are lighter than alpha particles, so no backscattering is possible kinetically.

Comment: The answer is Coulomb force goes like $\frac{1}{r}$, so if they will touch the force will be $\infty$